# ERROR: yum is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

Tags: vagrant, ansible, yum

Long story short my PC died while I was running Vagrant and when I got power back my subsequent vagrant up attempted to rebuild the box. In doing so I got an error as the subject is titled:

```
ERROR: yum is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
```

I've tried double checking the ansible documentation, checking my structure and indentation, saving in different text editors etc but the error persists. I'm stuck as there was no issue previously so I am a bit stumped as to why it's no longer working.

My playbook is as follows, though i've cut a lot of it out for now while I resolve the issue:

```
---
  - hosts: all
    sudo: yes
    tasks:
    - name: Update yum packages
      yum: name=* state=latest
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Is it possible something was corrupted in the power outage? I don't see anything clearly wrong here. Could you try a fresh vagrant box and a fresh install of Ansible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was missing a return after tasks.

```
---
  - hosts: all
    sudo: yes
    tasks:

    - name: Update yum packages
      yum: name=* state=latest
```

However ansible playbook docs: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html examples show that no return is required after the tasks declaration.

Perhaps a nuance with my particular version (1.7.2)